# Why are my checkboxes disappearing when I flatten the PDF?

Tags: pdfbox

I am trying to flatten my PDF's using the PDAcroForm [flatten method](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDAcroForm.html). The pdf I create is based on the example code for [PDFBox Checkbox creation](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java?view=markup) (I end up with a single page with one checkbox). However, when I call the flatten method on the PDF's Acroform, the checkbox I created disappears. Any idea what might be causing this?

Using PDFBox version: 2.0.5

Comment: Please try first updating to the current PDFBox version.

Comment: The current version is 2.0.19. The version 2.0.5 is from June 2017. There have been several bugfixes specifically related to disappearing fields when flattening.

Comment: Update: This bug was occurring when I would create unchecked checkboxes.

After reading another [StackOverflow answer by Matyas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383389/pdfbox-how-can-a-pdacroform-be-flattened/51273171#51273171), I needed to explicitly set the value of the checkbox as **unchecked**. When I was viewing the actual PDF structure, the new checkboxes that I added onto a PDF didn't have a `/V` value, but when I set the value to **unchecked** (which adds the `/V` value to `/Off`), then the flattening method didn't erase the checkboxes.

Comment: So you answered that question yourself => you can make that an answer. I'll change the example to add a comment. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer:**

This bug was occurring when I would create unchecked checkboxes.

After reading another [StackOverflow answer by Matyas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33383389/pdfbox-how-can-a-pdacroform-be-flattened/51273171#51273171), the **solution** was that I needed to **explicitly set the value** of the checkbox as **unchecked**.

I was able to verify the solution by viewing the actual PDF Structure. When I wasn't explicitly setting the checkbox value, the new checkboxes that I added onto a PDF didn't have a /V value (whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked). When I explicitly set the value to unchecked (which adds the /V value to /Off), then the flattening method didn't erase the checkboxes.

Please see an updated [example in PDFBOX Checkbox Creation](https://github.com/apache/pdfbox/blob/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/interactive/form/CreateCheckBox.java) to get the proper implementation.